# Filling array of missing values with respect to another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Need to fill the values for missing dates.
I'm having an array as follows,

```
// actual array
    var array1 = [{
    date: "2017-11-07",
    value: 23
    },
    {
    date: "2017-11-05",
    value: 30
    },
    {
    date: "2017-11-04",
    value: 24
    },
    {
    date: "2017-11-02",
    value: 23
    }];
```

I need the filled array like the below,

```
// expected result
    var array2 = [{
    date: "2017-11-01",
    value: 23
    },
    {
    date: "2017-11-02",
    value: 23
    },
{
    date: "2017-11-03",
    value: 23
    },
{
    date: "2017-11-04",
    value: 24
    },
{
    date: "2017-11-05",
    value: 30
    },
{
    date: "2017-11-06",
    value: 30
    },
{
    date: "2017-11-07",
    value: 23
    }];
```

Please advise me to how to make a loop to add the missing values with previous date value.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please update your post to include the code you've already tried.

Comment: Where do these other dates come from? Why are they missing and how are these values determined?

Comment: do you want it so that if date is less than current date then fill all missing dates with the previous object value ?

Comment: What are the date start and end rules and what values should be used?

Comment: @SagarBhattacharya, No, need to set the value for missing dates with the previous date. In the actual array, we have some dates missing. For example, there is no value for the date "2017-11-03, so we have to fill the value from the previous date i.e "2017-11-02".

Comment: @charlietfl, The start and end will be like, first and last date of the month(November in this case). For one month record, I have to set the missing date values with the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

At first its hard to work with a datestrig, lets define some conversion functions:

```
const toDate = str => ( split => new Date(split[0], split[1] - 1, split[2]) )(str.split("-")),
           toString = date => date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate(),
           DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
```

So then its probably good to sort the array, and we can store the real dates already:

```
array1.sort((a,b) => {
  a.time = toDate(a.date);
  b.time = toDate(b.date);
  return a.time - b.time;
});
```

So now we just need to fill in the gaps:

```
const add = [];
array1.reduce( (before, after, i) => {
  for(let time = +before.time + DAY; time < after.time; time += DAY)
     add.push({ value: before.value, time, date: toString(new Date(time))});
   return after;
});
```

The result will then be:

```
const array2 = array1.concat(add);
```

Comment: Thanks. Will try this